# tc lib barcode include letters

Tags: php, barcode, code128

I am using the [tc-lib-barcode](https://github.com/tecnickcom/tc-lib-barcode) library to create a barcode.
Creating it is not a problem but I want the letters of the barcode on the underside of it. How would I go on doing this?

```
$barcode = new Barcode();

$bObj = $barcode->getBarcodeObj(
    'C128',
    'testBarcode',
    1030,
    400
)->setBackgroundColor('white');
```

Comment: Echo them? Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @Andreas The letters should be included in the image.

Comment: If you have already solved it. Please advise how to do it, I am also struggling with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/) I just plopped a text image under the barcode:

```
$template->text($barcodeText, $barcodeX, $barcodeY + $barcodeHeight + $barcodeFontSize, function ($font) use ($barcodeFontSize) {
    $font->file(__DIR__ . '/cour.ttf');
    $font->size($barcodeFontSize);
});
```